# Is it possible to have a reasonably soundproof sliding door to a bedroom?

Tags: doors, noise, noise-reduction

We are planning a major house refurbishment, and in particular changing doors to two bedrooms. Our architect came up with this idea to put really wide sliding doors in, to get nice space after they are opened. I am a bit concerned with sound proofing though. Is it possible to make sliding doors reasonably soundproof? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the money there are some fantastic barn door style sliding doors made of solid wood that should give you better sound deadening than a normal hollow core interior door.

Any door made of solid wood or even foam core doors will perform better than glass or hollow core doors as far as sound deadening is concerned. The thicker the better.

Pretty is one thing but practical is another. I think solid wood does both.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of soundproofing is a very small hole in the soundproofing lets lots of noise thru.  If for instance the track the sliding door travels has a felt strip or thin rubber strip along its length, that will let lots of sound thru as it is mostly air or very thin.  Keep that in mind.  Doors typically have an air gap under them that allows air from the AC to flow out of the room to the return.  This gap under the door really affects the soundproofing.  If you get a sliding door make sure it is double pane.  Double panes drastically reduce noise transfer and will make a huge difference like it does on Mercedes car windows.  I put lots of effect in soundproofing a home theater room and floated walls and the floor, installed solid core interior doors, put a separate AC return in the room to allow for a sealed door, plus added thick 50 mil if I remember correctly vinyl in the walls.  Reduced almost all high pitched noise but only half to 2/3rds of the mid and low noises.  It made a difference but not as much as I'd hope.